# Windows 7 set IP address on an offline system

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking

I have a completely offline Windows 7 machine that I use for malware analysis. It's running VMware and I want to be able to SSH (using PuTTY) from my host machine into some Linux VMs, which would require an IP.

The problem is that I cannot set an IP address on my host machine, because the NIC isn't plugged into anything. `Local Area Connection` does not appear under `Connections` in the `Network and Sharing Center`, which makes sense becasue it's not active. The NIC is enabled and I can see it under `Control Panel -> Network and Internet -> Network Connections` just in a state of `Network cable unplugged` as it should be. I can go into the properties of the NIC here and manually set an IPv4 address, but it doesn't change anything. It shows as `Media disconnected` in `ipconfig`.

Is there any possible way to set an IP address on a Windows machine that isn't connected to anything? The only solution that I can think of at this point is to buy a cheap router and have this computer the only thing plugged into it.

Comment: What happens if you plug an Ethernet cable into the network card and nothing at the other end of the cable? You might get a `169.254.0.0/16` local link address.

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work. It's because the port doesn't become active unless some device is plugged in on the other side. I found a solution now, but thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Well if anyone finds this question, I was able to figure out a solution. I had to reconfigure the network settings of my VM's to use a custom virtual network. You can configure virtual networks in `Edit -> Virtual Network Editor`. On my host machine I had to enable the virtual NIC of that virtual network and allow it grab an IP automatically. The virtual NIC IP address is what your host machine will use to talk with the VM's.